# Angle between the sum of two vectors and the horizontal

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have 2 points, A + B, with vectors from the origin **a** and **b**. The vector from A to B is

**c** = **b** - **a** 
 
 
**a** and **b** are defined in polar coordinates with 
**a** $ = (r_a,\theta_a) $, **b** $ = (r_b,\theta_b ) $

I want to know how to define the angle **c** makes with the horizontal in terms of $\theta_a $ and/or $\theta_b$.

[image: vector angles]

Answer (score 1):

If it is an isosceles triangle, $\angle A=\angle B=90-\frac{\theta_a}{2}$

Extending $c$ down to the horizontal makes a triangle with angles $\theta_b,180-(90-\frac{\theta_a}{2}),\theta_c$. With $\theta_c$ being the angle you are after.  It can now be expressed in terms of $\theta_a$ and $\theta_b$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the case I'm thinking of would not have isosceles triangles although I've just realised I had a typo in the original, have corrected now. Sorry for the confusion! In general $r_a \neq r_b$

Comment: Ah. Then I believe the angle you are after will need to be in terms of 4 variables, the two angles and the two radii.

Answer (score 0):

You can find $A$ from the law of sines $\frac {\sin A}b=\frac{\sin \theta_a}c$ (but worry about whether the triangle is obtuse) or the law of cosines $b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac\cos A$  Then the angle you want is $\frac \pi2 - (\theta_a+\theta_b) - A$